# Emulate virtual hard drive using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, filesystems

Is it possible to sort of emulate a hard drive, utilizing Cocoa? I have a backup application, and I want my users to be able to browse their files outside of the app, in Finder, for example.

So, how would I be able to accomplish this? I know that some apps (Transmit) do it, but I have no idea how they do it. My best guess is that they add a folder somewhere in /Volumes, and then somehow mount it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should read about [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/). Read its Objective-C API [here](http://macfuse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/core/sdk-objc/Documentation/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it tomorrow. But since this is MacFuse, it would require the user to install MacFuse. Would I have to include it in my App bundle and significantly increase it's size, or could I download the latest version of MacFuse directly from some server? Then, there always is the question of how I will do my file system. It's probably just some file copied to some system folder I suppose, so updating it might get a little screwy rather quickly.

Comment: I think it is a little more complicated. File System stuff is difficult and it requires a lot of testing.